# 'Array' does not contain a Definition for 'OrderBy'

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a array of Jobs, but i have a issue where the JobName array provides me the error `Array does not contain a definition for OrderBy`. What do I have to do so that I can use the OrderBy with the array?

Comment: Can you add a example of your desired result?

Comment: Save the names as strings somewhere. Make it an array of tuples instead of integers, maybe. When you assign the value of an integer variable to a slot in an array (or to another integer variable), you're copying just the integer value itself -- just 32 bits of information. Just the value of the integer, nothing else. When you pour water out of a bottle into a bowl, the water doesn't retain any information about the color of the bottle it used to be in. If you want that extra information, store it explicitly.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this, i'm not sure I understand the syntax

Comment: Each of your jobs should be described using a class with two properties, name and time.

Comment: `Parse()` will throw an exception if the input can't be parsed; it's good practice to use [`TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.1) instead.

Comment: How would I do that with having a return value.

Comment: if you make a class you can override the `ToString` method to display name and time, if you make a tuple, you can access the first and second element to print it

Comment: How do you do that, can you provide an example please

Comment: do you know how to make a class in C# ? Here is a [good tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) on how to override the `ToString` method and use it for display

Comment: if you want to adress someone specifically by your comment put a `@` in front of the nick name like @ToManyProblems

Comment: @MongZhu I'm still having trouble figuring out how to apply the class to my code and still use an array as I have to sort the times.

Comment: You would use an array that can contain your class types : `MyClass[ ] array` and you would sort it using linq : `array = array.OrderBy( x=>x.JobTime).ToArray();`

Comment: @MongZhu Thanks, I think I understand

Comment: if you wrote the class, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47928637/edit) your post and add it. Then we can have a look

Comment: @MongZhu I have updated the code, but still getting an issue with reading in the time as using a string or int provide conflicting data types

Comment: @ToManyProblems since each instance of your class describes a *single* job, its name should ideally be singular to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Amy Would you happen to know how to get the console readline to provide the variable for JobTIme

Comment: @ToManyProblems here's a hint:  `Console.ReadLine()` returns a string, so you can't assign its result to an `int` variable.  (Not directly anyway)

Comment: @Amy so would this work '            Console.WriteLine("Job A Time (ms): ");
            string TimeOneText = Console.ReadLine();
            int JobTimeOne = int.Parse(TimeOneText);
            Jobs jobs = new Jobs { JobName = "A", JobTime = JobTimeOne };
            Console.WriteLine(jobs);'

Comment: Try it and find out.  It looks like it should.

Comment: you're almost there :)

Comment: @MongZhu I'm so close thank you two for the help it's been great, however, i'm having an issue with the added array for the JobNames 'Array' does not contain a Definition for 'OrderBy' . just edditing the question to include the code

Comment: Google that error.  We are here to help, but some of these issues are solved elsewhere and don't require individual attention.

Comment: @Amy yeah I'm close, thank you for the help

Comment: @ToManyProblems Hi, did you figure it out? please post the declaratino of the array and we can have a look

Answer (score 9):

[OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) is a linq method, you need the Namespace `System.Linq`

- `OrderBy` - Sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order according to a key.
- `OrderByDescending` - Sorts the elements of a sequence in descending order according to a key.

**Example with OrderBy**

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test.SO47928637
{
    public class Job
    {
        public string JobName { get; set; }
        public int JobTime { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Job{JobName}:{JobTime}";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the time for the following jobs");

            //record the times for the evaluation

            Console.WriteLine("Job A Time (ms): ");
            string timeOneText = Console.ReadLine();
            int jobTimeOne = int.Parse(timeOneText);
            Job jobA = new Job { JobName = "A", JobTime = jobTimeOne };
            Console.WriteLine(jobA);

            Console.WriteLine("Job B Time (ms): ");
            string timeTwoText = Console.ReadLine();
            int jobTimeTwo = int.Parse(timeTwoText);
            Job jobB = new Job { JobName = "B", JobTime = jobTimeTwo };
            Console.WriteLine(jobB);

            Console.WriteLine("Job C Time (ms): ");
            string timeThreeText = Console.ReadLine();
            int jobTimeThree = int.Parse(timeThreeText);
            Job jobC = new Job { JobName = "C", JobTime = jobTimeThree };
            Console.WriteLine(jobC);

            Console.WriteLine("Job D Time (ms): ");
            string timeFourText = Console.ReadLine();
            int jobTimeFour = int.Parse(timeFourText);
            Job jobD = new Job { JobName = "D", JobTime = jobTimeFour };
            Console.WriteLine(jobD);

            Console.WriteLine("Job E Time (ms): ");
            string timeFiveText = Console.ReadLine();
            int jobTimeFive = int.Parse(timeFiveText);
            Job jobE = new Job { JobName = "E", JobTime = jobTimeFive };
            Console.WriteLine(jobE);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();

            //Create an array for Job titles
            Job[] jobs = { jobA, jobB, jobC, jobD, jobE };

            var items = jobs.OrderBy(o => o.JobName);
            Console.WriteLine("Order by JobName ascending");
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }

            items = jobs.OrderBy(o => o.JobTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Order by JobTime ascending");
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }

            items = jobs.OrderByDescending(o => o.JobTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Order by JobTime descending");
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: beginner c# programmer here. this saved my day. thanks :)